# QgsAlignRaster extent

Tags: python, pyqgis

I am trying to align rasters in pyqgis (snap raster ArcMap equivalent).

There is a class reference in documentation, which is doing exactly what I need. QgsAlignRaster class.

Anyway, my problem is I can't get the extent right. If I put 2 rasters with different extent, like 2 overlapping rasters, the one which I want aligned will get clipped by the other, so I am missing almost half of the original raster.

Is there a way to set that I do not want  to clip it?

Documentation:
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/analysis/other/QgsAlignRaster.html

My code is:

```
def alignRaster(raster, raster_to_align, output, proj, cell_size):


 alignClass = QgsAlignRaster()
 item1 = QgsAlignRaster.Item(raster, "")
 item2 = QgsAlignRaster.Item(raster_to_align, output)

 alignClass.setRasters([item1, item2])
 alignClass.setParametersFromRaster(raster, proj)
 alignClass.setCellSize(cell_size,cell_size)
 alignClass.checkInputParameters()
 alignClass.createAndWarp(item2)
```

What i tried is setting the extent of raster with:

```
rLyr = QgsRasterLayer(raster)
clipExtent = rLyr.extent()
alignClass.setClipExtent(clipExtent)
```

I also tried setting clip extent to null, which is the default option I believe, since if I try to read the the clip extent, its says this:

```
print(alignClass.clipExtent())
>> <QgsRectangle: 0 0, 0 0>
```

I am out of ideas, is there a solution to my problem?

In the picture below, you can see how it gets clipped (gray raster is the new one)...

[image]

Comment: i have some idea about your problem,can you show me code with input parameters ?

Comment: Well, inputs are raster which I want aligned, raster which is ok, proj as WKT string of projection (EPSG:3979) and cell size, which is in this case 30x30m. and of course output to tiff file.

I also tried to solve it in QGIS desktop, but it does the same thing no matter the input parameters.